# Tensorflow 2.x - tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've problem with this line and using Tensorflow 2.3.1

```
if w_init is None:
        w_init = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
```

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib` was removed from tf2.0. When migrating code from tf1.0 it's probably one of the only few things that have to be changed. However, you can find the underlying modules elsewhere. Example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/VarianceScaling).

```
if w_init is None:
        w_init = tf.keras.initializers.variance_scaling()
```

Do go through this official documentation on [how to migrate from tf1.0 to tf2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).